# How not to continue a cancelled task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Here is a sample code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });
task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Exception"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Success"), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
    .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Should not be executed. Task status = " + t.Status, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled));
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is (the order does not matter):

> Exception
>
> Should not be executed. Task status = Canceled

Why was the second ContinueWith executed and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because typo, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> it.

```
// ContinueWith([NotNull] Action<Task> continuationAction)
// WriteLine([NotNull] string format, object arg0)
.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Should not be executed. Task status = " + t.Status, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled));

// ContinueWith([NotNull] Action<Task> continuationAction, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions)
// WriteLine(string value) 
.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Should not be executed. Task status = " + t.Status), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);
```

Comment: Oh, no way... It is really just a typo and it works correctly. Thanks you a lot!!!
Everyone, sorry for disturbing with no reason!

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses in your last call to `ContinueWith` are wrong:

```
.ContinueWith(t =>
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Should not be executed. Task status = " + t.Status,
        TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled));
```

`TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled` is being passed as an argument to `WriteLine`.

Fixed:

```
.ContinueWith(t =>
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Should not be executed. Task status = " + t.Status),
    TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Will be more attentive next time.

Comment: @TeddyBo I missed it at first as well! It's just one of those subtle problems that can creep up from function overloading, `params object[]` parameters, etc.